# get GCP cloud function logs label.executionid

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

i want to get the execution id, that GCP gave to the Cloud functions, in order to store it in a database.

[image: Logs]

this is what i want to get =>

```js
let currId = log.label.execution_id
```

In order to do it i'm fetching the logs thanks to this function (inside my cloudFunctions):

```js
const logging = new Logging();
console.log(`executed ${eId}`)
printEntryMetadata(eId, sId);

async function printEntryMetadata(eId, sId) {
    const options = {
        filter: `textPayload = "executed ${eId}"`
    };
    
    const [entries] = await logging.getEntries(options);
    console.log('Logs:');
    console.log(`textPayload = "executed ${eId}"`)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(entries))
    // const metadata = entries[0].metadata
    console.log(`${metadata.labels.execution_id}`)
}
```

But the `JSON.stringify(entries)` return an empty array. And when i use the filter mannualy it's working...
is the cloud function unable to fetch it own logs?

Comment: Can you share more details? Like what code are you already using to fetch these logs at the moment?

Comment: sry for this late response...
btw i've edited the question :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what i've done:

```js
exports.LogMetadata = async(executionId, scopeId, ProjectID, Logging) => {
    const logging = new Logging({ProjectID});
    const options = {
        filter: `textPayload = "executed ${executionId}.${scopeId}"`
    };
    
    const [entries] = await logging.getEntries(options);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(entries))
    try {
        const metadata = entries[0].metadata
        console.log(`${metadata.labels.execution_id}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("can't find the log, cause' it's the first function executed...")
    }

}
```

The only thing that doesn't work is that i can't fetch the first log of the first esxecuted function.